# Writing tuple data into a file using a loop

Tags: c++, iostream

I want to write/read a tuple into a BIN file. I know how to write/read each element of the tuple, but the tuple has 13 elements and I would rather make this all at once using a loop. But I have been unable to do so.

This is the code that I have tried:

```
#include <fstream>

template <typename T>
std::ostream& writeBin(std::ostream& f, T data) {
    return f.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&data), sizeof(data));
}
std::ostream& writeBin(std::ostream& f, const std::string& str) {
    std::string::size_type sz = str.size();
    if (f) { f.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&sz), sizeof(sz)); }
    if (f) { f.write(str.data(), str.size()); }
    return f;
}

template <typename T>
std::istream& readBin(std::istream& f, T& data) {
    if (f) { f.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&data), sizeof(data)); }
    return f;
}
std::istream& readBin(std::istream& f, std::string& str) {
    std::string::size_type sz = 0;
    if (f) { f.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&sz), sizeof(sz)); }
    if (f) { str.resize(sz); f.read(str.data(), sz); }
    return f;
}

class Data {
public:
    Data() {};
    ~Data() {};
    std::tuple<std::string, std::string, int, int, int, int, std::string, int, int, int, int, int, int>tup{
        " "," ",0,0,0,0," ",0,0,0,0,0,0
    };
    bool write(std::ofstream& f);
    bool read(std::ifstream& f);
};

bool Data::write(std::ofstream& f) {
    std::apply([](auto&&... tArg) {
        ((if (!writeBin(f, tArg)) { return false; }), ...);//doesnt work
        }, tup);
    return true;
}

bool Data::read(std::ifstream& f) {
    std::apply([](auto&&... tArg) {
        ((if (!readBin(f, tArg)) { return false; }), ...);//doesnt work
        }, tup);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: "doesn't work" is not a compiler error or a wrong result. What _specifically_ happens? Paste error messages into the question.